# In loopback4 have any distribution folder that we can use to publish in production?

Tags: strongloop, loopback4

Which we can use to publish in production rather pulling the entire source code in to the server??

Answer (score 0):

The recommended and supported way to deploy a LoopBack 4 application is to use the entire source code. If need be, the project can be pre-built and the `src` directory along with other build artifacts can be removed from production.

Further reading

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Deployment.html